# Configuring Docker on Ubuntu Server in Microsoft Azure to run a Grails App

Tags: azure, grails

I was running my Grails app in a virtual machine created through Azure. But I learned that running my app in a Docker container can be very beneficial. So I resolved to create a container and run the app in it. Now the thing is that I am very confused how should I create that container in my virtual machine and specifically what steps to follow to run the app in it. I have read a lot of blogs about it but still can't find a straight forward solution. Should I have to create a new virtual machine and configure it? or can it be done otherwise.

Comment: Does this help http://nimavat.me/blog/deploy-grails-application-war-to-tomcat-docker-container

Comment: Thank you very much @Sudhir N ....it has started to make sense

Comment: If you have docker and docker-compose installed in your virtual machine, you should be able to follow the steps in above link and should be able to deploy your app to tomcat/mysql